Is it correct to say "You buttoned your shirt unevenly"?

A child is putting on a shirt. He is buttoning his shirt wrong.
His 2nd button went through the 1st hole, his 3rd button went through the 2nd hole and his 4th button went through the 3rd hole (see the above picture).
This is my sentence "Oh, you got your buttons through the wrong holes".
But I am not sure if there is a more natural way to express it?
For example, "You buttoned your shirt unevenly".

unevenly is far less natural than "you have your buttons in the wrong holes".

Using unevenly makes it sound as though a button or a hole was skipped in the middle, as if the buttoning is correct at the top but not at the bottom.

Since this is a common and informal situation, especially within a family, there’s no need for detailed descriptions.
Simple sentences like the ones below are natural and easily understood by a child:

"You got the buttons mixed up."
"You buttoned your shirt wrong."
"Your shirt is buttoned incorrectly."
"You put the buttons in the wrong holes."


I did this a lot at a certain age, and my mother used no. 4 usually.

The wrong holes version is clearer and should be good enough.  An added simple gesture to the child will remove all doubts.

holes not wholes

Thanks, @Stuart F.   I was careless!
